# Error message with python in jGrasp about path

Tags: python, path, jgrasp

So, I have just recently installed jgrasp on my computer. I have just selected the standard installation. For this particular instance, I am writing in python. However, whenever I try to run my code, I get an error message that the command python is not defined, and is in the wrong path. I have tried redirecting the path in startup settings as well as following troubleshooting guides about environmental variables on google, but it still does not work.

Here is the error message:

> jGRASP wedge error: command "python" not found.
>       This command must be in the current Working directory
>       or on the current PATH to use this function.
>       working directory is "C:\Acc CS".
>       PATH is ";C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem; 
>   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\".
>   jGRASP: operation complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install Python if you haven't already. For Windows, you can get it here: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows

You may want to get both Python 2 and 3 depending on what you are doing. They are quite different syntactically, so if you are working with existing code you will need to choose the correct one. Also in jGRASP you should choose Python 2 or 3 in the compiler settings to get the correct syntax coloring and CSD generation (default in jGRASP is Python 2).

If you already have Python installed, either add the directory containing python.exe to the system PATH in Windows, or use "Settings" > "PATH / CLASSPATH" > "Workspace" in jGRASP to add it for jGRASP only.